# MongoDB order of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

my application has a list of the games. Each game has a position(in which order to show it to users: 1, 2, 3...).

I'm using MongoDB to keep all the data. Ok, so now I have the game with position 4 for example. And I want to change it to position 1. So what I need to do?

I need to update field position for this game in MongoDB from 4 to 1, and to do increment to all documents in this collection that following after position 1.

But I think it's not very good idea! May be you have ideas how to implement it in better way? Thanks!

Example of the mongo table:

```
_id             | name    | description      | position |
________________________________________________________
ObjectId("...") | bubble  | some description | 1
ObjectId("...") | bubbleA | some description | 2
ObjectId("...") | bubbleB | some description | 3
ObjectId("...") | bubbleC | some description | 4
ObjectId("...") | bubbleD | some description | 5
ObjectId("...") | bubbleE | some description | 6
ObjectId("...") | bubbleF | some description | 7
```

So now in my site I'm showing games in order: bubble -> bubbleA -> bubbleB -> bubbleC...
And now I want to show in my site games in order: bubbleC -> bubbleA -> bubbleB -> bubble...
So to do it I need to update "position" field in my table for "bubbleC" to "1", and increment all other "positions" for all documents after document with name "bubble". But it's a bad idea. So how to do it better?

Comment: People cannot really suggest how to "move your data around" unless your show real data and what you are trying to do. Please edit your question.

Comment: Updated my post, hope it's more clear now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach isn't that bad if you have a relatively small number of documents and don't change positions a lot.

As an alternative you could store the positional metadata in a separate array. Position updates would only touch one document. Basic Python example:

```python
def move(positions, old_index, new_index):
    element = positions.pop(old_index)
    positions.insert(new_index, element)
    return positions

# Fetch array from MongoDB (or from anywhere really)
positions = [
    { '_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'name': "bubble",  'description': "some description" },
    { '_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'name': "bubbleA", 'description': "some description" },
    { '_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'name': "bubbleB", 'description': "some description" },
    { '_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'name': "bubbleC", 'description': "some description" },
    { '_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'name': "bubbleD", 'description': "some description" },
    { '_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'name': "bubbleE", 'description': "some description" },
    { '_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'name': "bubbleF", 'description': "some description" }
]

old_index = 3
new_index = 0
move(positions, old_index, new_index)

# New positions:
#
# [{'_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'description': 'some description', 'name': 'bubbleC'},   <--
#  {'_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'description': 'some description', 'name': 'bubble'},
#  {'_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'description': 'some description', 'name': 'bubbleA'},
#  {'_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'description': 'some description', 'name': 'bubbleB'},
#  {'_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'description': 'some description', 'name': 'bubbleD'},
#  {'_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'description': 'some description', 'name': 'bubbleE'},
#  {'_id': 'ObjectId("...")', 'description': 'some description', 'name': 'bubbleF'}]
```

Writing a small helper function would help with moving elements around by `_id` or `name`.